# Javascript onmouseover event

Tags: javascript, hover, onmouseover

In this image, when I'm hovering over the javascript link, it shows some text attached with the cursor. What is that text called, and how can we put it in use in our web pages?

[image]

Comment: It's the `title` attribute: `<a href="https://google.com" title="Hello">Google</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If hovering over a browser tab, the text that appears is generated from the `<title>` tag within the `<head>` section of the html page it belongs to, the below is the example from this page:

```
<title>hover - Javascript onmouseover event - Stack Overflow</title>
```

The text that appears when hovering over an on page element is generated from the title attribute such as `<img src="cat.png" title="A photo of a cat">`, its primary use being to provide advisory information for the element it belongs to. If an element has no title attribute, it will inherit its title from its parent.